# Distance between probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Is there an equivalent of KL divergence between probability measures that
are not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

I am interested in rigorous notions of typical and atypical (rare)
trajectories in a dynamical system. We can assume uniform hyperbolicity
for simplicity and the existence and smoothness of an SRB measure. Then,
I would like to say something like this: If I have a trajectory 
that behaves as if it was generated by a probability measure $\mu$, 
then, I would consider this trajectory $\epsilon$-atypical
if there is a set $A \subset S$ such that $\mu < \epsilon$ and $\mu_{SRB} > 1 - \epsilon$.

It would be nice if there was a global definition of distance between
$\mu$ and $\mu_{SRB}$ that would allow an extension to Sanov's theorem
to make rigorous how likely it is to encounter a rare trajectory.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: The KL divergence merely requires the two distributions to be absolutely continuous with respect to *some* third measure, not necessarily the Lebesgue or counting measure. But even without that there are probability measure metrics out there, just depends on the analysis you are actually doing...

Comment: You can always use total variation; in some sense KL divergence represents distance, but since it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality some weird stuff can happen when thinking of it as a notion of distance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am specifically searching for the correct metric to use to derive an extension of Sanov's theorem